# How can I verify my linear program solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, simplex

I started solving linear programs with the Simplex algorithm, however it is unclear to me how can I *verify* my solutions.

I have heard about geometrical solutions easy to check visually, but I'd rather do it just with algebra. How can I verify my linear program solutions?

For context, here is the particular problem I just solved I'd like to verify:

---

$$max \ (3x_1-x_2)$$
$$\begin{cases}
x_1-x_2 \le 3\\
\color{red}{2x_1\le x_2}\\
x_1+x_2\ge 12\\
x_2 \le 10\\
x_1,x_2 \ge 0
\end{cases}$$

Change it to

$$\begin{cases}
x_1-x_2 \le 3\\
\color{red}{2x_1 - x_2 \le 0}\\
x_1+x_2\ge 12\\
x_2 \le 10\\
x_1,x_2 \ge 0
\end{cases}$$

I transform it to the standard form...

$$\begin{cases}
x_1-x_2 + x_3 = 3\\
2x_1 - x_2 + 0 + x_4 = 0\\
x_1+x_2 + 0 + 0 - x_5 = 12\\
0 + x_2 + 0 + 0 + 0 + x_6 = 10\\
x_1,x_2 \ge 0
\end{cases}$$

---

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 12 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 10 \\
3 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

The pivot column is the second one, and the pivot row is the fourth. So we got our pivot:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 12 \\
0 & [1] & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 10 \\
3 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$r_4 + r_1$$
$$r_4 + r_2$$
$$-r_4 + r_3$$
$$r_4 + r_5$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 13 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 10 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 2 \\
0 & [1] & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 10 \\
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 10
\end{bmatrix}$$

The objective row has no negative terms, so we're done. The basic feasible solution here is

$$(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6) = (0,10,13,10,0,0)$$

Now we evaluate this solution with the objective function:

$$3x_1-x_2 = 3(0)-10 = -10$$

Comment: If you look at the $x_1 + x_2 \geq 12$ constraint, does your answer satisfy it?

Comment: @NigelOvermars: Good thing I'm seeking a way to verify those answers :D

Comment: It puzzles me though - I can't quite find the flaw in the procedure.

Comment: Do you know how the Simplex algorithm works geometrically?

Comment: @NigelOvermars: Somewhat - you kind of draw a polygon based on the constraints and inspect to see what would be the maximum and minimum values? However, I may be wrong, but doesn't this only work if you are using two variables? Three or more wouldn't be possible I think?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wcbj3cj5blqcpbv/03%20SimplexMethod1%20Handouts2pp.pdf https://www.dropbox.com/s/3unno1uvx1rv5gt/04%20SimplexMethod2%20Handouts2pp.pdf

Comment: The parts about the M-method and two-phase method are most relevant for you, but it might be useful to look at the rest, since you do not quite understand how the Simplex algorithm works.

Answer (score 0):

For verifying a solution, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maximize%5B%7B3%2ax1+-+x2%2C++++x1+-+x2+%3C%3D+3+%26%26+2+x1+%3C%3D+x2+%26%26+x1+%2B+x2+%3E%3D+12+%26%26+x2+%3C%3D+10+%26%26+x1+%3E%3D+0+%26%26+++++x2+%3E%3D+0%7D%2C+%7Bx1%2C+x2%7D%5D) might be useful (also free and fast) if you do not actually have *Mathematica*. I actually wrote the following up in *Mathematica* then pasted that into WA. You should be able to duplicate this for your other checks:

```
Maximize[{3*x1 - x2, 
x1 - x2 <= 3 && 2 x1 <= x2 && x1 + x2 >= 12 && x2 <= 10 && x1 >= 0 &&
x2 >= 0}, {x1, x2}]
```

Note that `Minimize` works similarly.